# Loop to copy values from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have 2 sheets, sourcesheet and acct sheet. From sourceSheet I need to copy the values from sourceSheet.Range(Cells(14, 3),Cells(14, 8)) to  AcctSheet.range(Cells(2, 11),Cells(7, 11)), however each cell from sourcesheet is distinct matched to acctsheet, in such a way that

```
sourceSheet.Cells(14, 3) = AcctSheet.Cells(2, 11)
sourceSheet.Cells(14, 4) = AcctSheet.Cells(3, 11)
sourceSheet.Cells(14, 5) = AcctSheet.Cells(4, 11) and so on until
sourceSheet.Cells(14, 8) = AcctSheet.Cells(7, 11)
```

Code is here, but hoping to loop this one.

```vb
sourceSheet.Activate
    'EQ
    If IsEmpty(sourceSheet.Cells(14, 3).Value) Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(2, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value   
    ElseIf sourceSheet.Cells(14, 3).Value < sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(2, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(14, 3).Value 
    ElseIf sourceSheet.Cells(14, 3).Value > sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(2, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value   
    End If
    'WS
    If IsEmpty(sourceSheet.Cells(14, 4).Value) Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(3, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value   
    ElseIf sourceSheet.Cells(14, 4).Value < sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(3, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(14, 4).Value 
    ElseIf sourceSheet.Cells(14, 4).Value > sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(3, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value   
    End If
    'TO
    If IsEmpty(sourceSheet.Cells(14, 5).Value) Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(4, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value   
    ElseIf sourceSheet.Cells(14, 5).Value < sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(4, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(14, 5).Value 
    ElseIf sourceSheet.Cells(14, 5).Value > sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(4, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value   
    End If
    'FL
    If IsEmpty(sourceSheet.Cells(14, 6).Value) Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(5, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value   
    ElseIf sourceSheet.Cells(14, 6).Value < sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(5, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(14, 6).Value 
    ElseIf sourceSheet.Cells(14, 6).Value > sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(5, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value   
    End If
    'FR
    If IsEmpty(sourceSheet.Cells(14, 7).Value) Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(6, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value   
    ElseIf sourceSheet.Cells(14, 7).Value < sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(6, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(14, 7).Value 
    ElseIf sourceSheet.Cells(14, 7).Value > sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(6, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value   
    End If
    'TR
    If IsEmpty(sourceSheet.Cells(14, 8).Value) Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(7, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value   
    ElseIf sourceSheet.Cells(14, 8).Value < sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(7, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(14, 8).Value 
    ElseIf sourceSheet.Cells(14, 8).Value > sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value Then
        AcctSheet.Cells(7, 11).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value   
    End If
```

Comment: You have `<` and `>` but nothing if `=`, is that intended ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, acctSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sourceCell As Range, targetCell As Range, defaultCell As Range
    
    Set defaultCell = sourceSheet.Cells(7, 1)
    
    For i = 3 To 8
    
        Set sourceCell = sourceSheet.Cells(14, i)
        Set targetCell = acctSheet.Cells(i - 1, 11)
        
        If IsEmpty(sourceCell) Then
            targetCell.Value2 = sourceCell.Value2
        ElseIf sourceCell.Value2 < defaultCell.Value2 Then
            targetCell.Value2 = sourceCell.Value2
        ElseIf sourceCell.Value2 > defaultCell.Value2 Then
            targetCell.Value2 = defaultCell.Value2
        End If
        
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Strictly speaking, I don't think you need to include `.Value2` after every cell, as VBA kinda uses that as the default when reading the code, but it doesn't hurt.

Using variables for the cell references isn't strictly necessary either, but I find it easier, especially if I need to edit the cell references later.

Comment: oh my god! thank you! that answers my problem!